# Generate options category list with PHP instead of xml

Tags: magento2, category-products, select

I have a list of options grouped by category

[image]

I did it with xml

```
   <field name="categorie_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">categorie_id</item>
                <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="newOption" xsi:type="string">toggleOptionSelected</item>
                </item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">conditions</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Now I want to do the same thing with PHP

```
$fieldset->addField
```